# finding the type of an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, if I have a reference to an element, how can I determine what kind of element it is, for example, an input or an dropdown?  Is there any way to find out?

Duplicate:

[How can I determine the element type of a matched element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341900/how-can-i-determine-the-element-type-of-a-matched-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341900/how-can-i-determine-the-element-type-of-a-matched-element-in-jquery

Comment: May be a duplicate, but it has a better answer, and the other one is tagged badly.

Comment: @Rumpleteaser If "the other one" is tagged badly, then why don't you make use of `edit` button below it and tag it perfectly?

Answer (score 617, accepted):

The following will return true if the element is an input:

```
$("#elementId").is("input")
```

or you can use the following to get the name of the tag:

```
$("#elementId").get(0).tagName
```

Comment: When using $("#elementId").get(0).tagName the tagName will be in all caps - TR, DIV etc etc

Comment: okay, so the tagName property returns an all caps value, I just did a `.toLowerCase()` on it

Comment: `var elementType = $(this).prop('tagName');`

Comment: Using `nodeName` might be more consistent across different browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename

Comment: Note, that using `$("#elementId").is(":input")` will generally tell you, if you're dealing with any kind of form element, without checking for its specific type ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11689147/1469208)).

Answer (score 14):

You can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** with `tagName` as the name of the property that you want to get:

```
$("#elementId").prop('tagName');
```

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that @Marius's second answer could be used as pure Javascript solution.

```
document.getElementById('elementId').tagName
```