# Determine if an element is a form field

Tags: jquery, dom

Any convenient ways to determine if a selected element is a form field, i.e is an input, select, checkbox etc?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.is(':input')` to test if it's any kind of form element.

Docrefs:

- http://api.jquery.com/is/ - *Check the current matched set of elements against a selector...*
- http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ - *Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."*

Comment: Sometimes I just love jQuery. :)

Comment: Yes, `:input` (with the colon) is a pseudo selector that matches them all. The docs say so, too, btw: *"Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements."*

Comment: The scope of the selector might not be enough if WebComponents with attached internals are involved, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76471469/343721) (posted as an answer due to formatting and length limits).

Answer (score 5):

Use plain javascript:

```
$("#someelement")[0].tagName // will return name of tag (div, p, input, select, etc...)
```

The first index `[0]` of any jQuery object will return its DOM object. To do it completely in javascript:

```
document.getElementById("someelement").tagName;
```

Comment: Occurred to me that this is also possible:

`var accept = ["FORM", "INPUT", "SELECT"];`

`accept.indexOf($("#someelement")[0].tagName);`

Comment: Right, just remember that `indexOf` returns the index of the array (`>=0`) that the value is matched to, and returns -1 if the search string is not in the array.

Answer (score 2):

In pure **JavaScript** you could do something like the [Sizzle Engine](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle)

```
/^(?:input|select|textarea|button)$/i.test(el?.nodeName)
```

Example

```js
/**
 * Test is form action element
 * @param {Object} el 
 * @return {Boolean} true if a form action element
 */
const isInput = el => /^(?:input|select|textarea|button)$/i.test(el?.nodeName);


// DEMO:
document.querySelectorAll('.foo').forEach(el => console.log(isInput(el)));
```

```html
<textarea class="foo">test</textarea>
<button class="foo">test</button>
<input class="foo" type="text">
<div class="foo">test</div>
<p class="foo">test</p>
```

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/src/sizzle.js#L139

Comment: Fails if `el` is null, [null is also object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511350/343721).

Comment: Edited and should be fixed now. @JanTuroň

Answer (score 0):

After a decade, `.is(":input")` may not be enough, as the [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

> selects **[only]** all input, textarea, select and button elements

but we can also have [WebComponents with attached internals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementInternals) which can act as form fields, too.

To determine if the element is a form field, the plain javascript would be

```
function isFormField(elem) {
  // elem is expected to be HTMLElement instance
  return "value" in elem;
}
```

...or, if you love jQuery, it can be simplified to *awesome* concise extension

```
$.fn.isFormField = function(index=0) {
  let elem = this.get(index);
  if (!(elem instanceof HTMLElement)) return false;
  return "value" in elem;
}

if ($(myElement).isFormField()) ...
```

...or, if you use ES6+, there is a *complicated* way to code it, which just sucks

```
const isFormField = elem => elem instanceof HTMLElement && "value" in elem;

if (isFormField(myElement)) ...
```

I hope I used the jQuery terminology correctly.

Answer (score -1):

$('#formid').find('id_element');

[jquery find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Hope this helped

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question

Comment: with this he can determine if there's an element is in a form.