# How to determine which selector is selected from among the rest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code:

**HTML:**

```
// import jQuery

<tr id = "tr_id">
  <td>something</td>
  <td>something</td>
</tr>

<div>
  <span class = "cls">something</span>
  <a id="a_id" href="#">something</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var result;
$("tr, .cls").on("click", function(){

    if (/* selector is "tr" */) {
      result = $(this).attr("id");
    } else{
      result = $(this).closest("a").attr("id");
    }

});
```

---

Now I want to know how can I write a condition in this `if` statement?

```
if (/* selector is "tr" */) {
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding the type of an element using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608410/finding-the-type-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Comment: `this.tagName` is a really fast way if you need perf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.is(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) at this context,

```
$("tr, .cls").on("click", function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  result = $this.is("tr") ? $this.attr("id") : $this.closest("a").attr("id");
});
```

Comment: re "_it has a function for everything_", yeah, and that's not even it's biggest problem ;)

Comment: Sorry to ping you again, but in reality my code is different a bit. May you please tell me how can I use `.is()` in [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/to0zjLpo/) ?

Comment: @stack Its ok man. Here you go. https://jsfiddle.net/to0zjLpo/1/ See the usage of `.bind()` in the code given.