# Difference between .tagName and .nodeName

Tags: javascript, dom, tagname, nodename

What is the difference between `$('this')[0].nodeName` and `$('this')[0].tagName`?

Comment: This question is more of a dom question because it isn't specific to jquery.

Answer (score 146):

The [`tagName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) is meant specifically for *element nodes* (type 1 nodes) to get the type of *element*.

There are several [other types of nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) as well (comment, attribute, text, etc.). To get the name of any of the various node types, you can use the [`nodeName` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName).

When using `nodeName` against an *element node*, you'll get its tag name, so either could really be used, though you'll get [better consistency between browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t23) when using `nodeName`.

Answer (score 53):

[This](http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/) is a pretty good explanation of the difference between the two.

---

Added text from the article:

> `tagName` and `nodeName` are both useful Javascript properties for
>   checking the name of an html element. For most purposes, either will
>   do fine but nodeName is preferred if you are supporting only A-grade
>   browsers and tagName is preferred if you intend to support IE5.5 as
>   well.
>
> There are two issues with `tagName`:
>
> - In all versions of IE, tagName returns `!` when called on a comment node
> - For text nodes, tagName returns `undefined` whereas nodeName returns `#text`
>
> `nodeName` has its own set of [issues](http://web.archive.org/web/20160402120625/http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t20) but they are less severe:
>
> - IE 5.5 returns `!` when called on a comment node. This is less harmful than tagName which suffers from this behaviour across *all*
>     versions of IE
> - IE 5.5 doesn’t support nodeName for the `document` element or for attributes. Neither of these should be a concern for most practical
>     purposes but should be kept in mind in any case
> - Konqueror ignores comment nodes when using this property. But then again, Konqueror, along with IE 5.5 is not an [A-grade browser](http://web.archive.org/web/20160402120625/http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/)
>
> So for most practical purposes stick to `nodeName` due to its support
>   for a wider range of scenarios and potentially better forward
>   compatibility. Not to mention that it doesn’t hiccup on a comment
>   node, which has a tendency to creep into code unannounced. Don’t worry
>   about IE 5.5 or Konqueror as their market share is near 0%.

Answer (score 17):

Read about those properties in the DOM Core spec.

`nodeName` is a property defined in the Node interface
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095

`tagName` is a property defined in the Element interface
http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-104682815

btw the Node interface is implemented by every node in the DOM tree (including the `document` object itself). The Element interface is implemented only by those nodes in the DOM tree that represent elements in an HTML document (nodes with `nodeType` === 1) .

Answer (score 8):

And this is what happens on Firefox 33 and Chrome 38:

HTML:

```
<div class="a">a</div>
```

Js:

```
node = e
node.nodeType === 1
node.nodeName === 'DIV'
node.tagName  === 'DIV'

node = e.getAttributeNode('class')
node.nodeType === 2
node.nodeName === 'class'
node.tagName  === undefined

node = e.childNodes[0]
node.nodeType === 3
node.nodeName === '#text'
node.tagName  === undefined
```

So:

- only use `nodeType` to get the node type: `nodeName` breaks for `nodeType === 1`
- only use `tagName` for `nodeType === 1`

Comment: How does "`nodeName` break for `nodeType === 1`"?

Comment: @WD40 better late than never. Have you read the linked documentation in which it is written that `The read-only Node.nodeType property is an integer that identifies what the node is.` ?

Comment: @snr I just read it. According to MDN, nodeType 1 is ELEMENT_NODE. Accessing nodeName of an HTMLElement works fine for me. So I again ask: what is broken?

Comment: @WD40 I don't remember anymore, but what I think I meant by "it breaks" is: unlike for other node types, you don't get a description of what kind of node you have (e.g. something like `elem`?) but rather the same of `tagName` which is different for each elem. So you would likely want to always use `nodeType` to detect node type and `tagName` for the tag name.