# Get the current element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I find the el tag name below (eg. div, p or span) ?

```
$('div, p, span').each(function(){ 
  var el = $(this);



});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `nodeName` is better than `tagName` if you consider consistency between browsers.
This has good explanation: [Difference between .tagName and .nodeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/different-between-tagname-and-nodename-jquery)

```
$('div, p, span').each(function(){ 
  var el = this.nodeName;
});
```

Comment: There won't be any other type of nodes than tags in a collection created from that selector. Actually, there will never be any other type of nodes in a jQuery collection created from *any* selector.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `tagName` property:

```
$('div, p, span').each(function(){ 
  var tag = this.tagName;
});
```

Note: `tagName` is a property of the element, not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("p,div").bind('click',function(){
       var el = this.tagName;
       alert(el);
    });
});
</Script>
<p>p</p>
<div>div</div>
```

....

more info (example) [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScriptReference/Javascript-Properties/tagNameExample.htm)

Comment: That doesn't work, there is no tagName property in the jQuery object. (I even tried it, to be 100% sure.)

Comment: yes, sorry. It will work now. working demo: http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e26a7.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(this).prop('tagName')
```

or

```
$(e.target).prop('tagName')
```

to get the selected tag name.