# How to identify tags in a node list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="aa1"><h1>aaaa</h1><h2 class="center">bbbb</h2></div>
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
var list= document.getElementById("aa1").childNodes;
```

I get a node list that looks like this:

```
list= NodeList[h1,h2.center]
```

but, if my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="aa1"><h3>cccc</h3><h1>aaaa</h1><h2 class="center">bbbb</h2></div>
```

I get a node list that looks like this:

```
list= NodeList[h3,h1,h2.center]
```

So, I would like to do something like this:

```
if(list[0]==="<h3>"){console.log("yes, list[0] = <h3>");}
```

but that doesn't work.

How can I get identities of each tag in the node list?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: Are you looking for the [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.tagName) property? (Or, wait, [`nodeName` is better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.nodeName` property.

```
if(list[0].nodeName==="H3"){console.log("yes, list[0] = <h3>");}
```

there are some rare edge cases where the name could be returned lowercase, so for extra safety, you could add `.toUpperCase()` after `.nodeName`.

---

Also, though you don't have text nodes to contend with, if you did, you could use `.children` instead of `.childNodes`.

Comment: it works with a capital "H3". wow! I never have figured that out. Thanks so much