# Determine a jQuery selector's element type

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have two `DOM` element like this:

`<img id="test1" src="xyz" />`

`<a id="test2" href="#">Test 2</a>`

And I'm selecting them in jQuery like this:

`$('#test1')` and `$('#test2')`

I want to be able to return `img` and `a` respectively. Using either vanilla Javascript or jQuery, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "return `img` and `a`"? Do you mean a string 'img' or 'a'? Or an object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to get a reference to the DOM element and use the native `nodeName` property.

You can do this with jQuery: `$('#test1').prop('nodeName').toLowerCase()`

Or with vanilla js: `document.getElementById('test1').nodeName.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Given the question, it might be worth throwing a `toLowerCase()` in there as well (though I don't know if that's a specific request).

Comment: @DavidThomas good suggestion, I actually didn't consider that myself and you probably just saved me a good hour or two of future debugging! Upvotes for you.

Comment: Stick with `nodeName`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename . And instead of `.get(0).tagName`, you could use `.prop("tagName")` (or `nodeName`)

Comment: @Ian I didn't know about `nodeName`; thanks!