# How to get the type of the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, dom

In a dropdown I want to get a custom attribute from my options element:

```
<select name="t" id="t">
    <option value="all">- all -</option>
    <optgroup label="Europe">
        <option selected value="1" myAttr="1">Fr</option>
        <option value="2" myAttr="0">Uk</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="America">
        <option value="3" myAttr="1">USA</option>
        <option value="4" myAttr="0">CA</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Asia">
        <option value="5" myAttr="0">JP</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

So I first loop over `optgroup` tags, and then I loop over `option` one's ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/6Gw6d/1/)).

```
var temp = document.getElementById("t").childNodes;
// Loop the optGroup
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    // Loop the option
    for (var j = 0; j < temp[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
```

Then I want to test if my element is an *HTMLOptionElement* before getting my custom attribute, I tried some tips from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class), but without success, I always get 'undefined'. Is thhre a specific method to use with DOM elements?

Comment: `window.console.log(temp[i].childNodes[j].nodeName);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878484/106261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [nodeName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeName) :

```
var div1 = document.getElementById("d1");
var div1Type = div1.nodeName;
```

And the difference between [nodeName and tagName](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4878484/106261).

Answer (score 1):

**[Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName)** - *Returns the name of the element.*

Answer (score 1):

Every DOM element has a tagName attribute that you can use: myChildNode.tagName