# Equivalent of jQuery code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the jQuery code I have

```
$('p').click(function(){
    alert("click successful!");
});
```

This is the JS code I could come up with

```
window.onload = function() {
    var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    for(var i = 0; i < para.length; i++) {
        para[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
            alert("click successful!");
        });
    }
}
```

The Javascript code is too bulky, is there a way where I can select a tag by its name and write the code as -

> "If any 'p' tag is clicked, alert('click successful')"

instead of looping through all the `<p></p>` tags?
Any alternative way using **tag name**?

Comment: do you want do it without using jquery?

Comment: Do the paragraphs already exist or are they being dynamically added?

Comment: @kakajan yes, I want to do it without jQuery

Comment: @Jezzabeanz, yes they already exist

Comment: Why you are want to do it without jQuery if pure JS is too bulky for you? =)

Comment: @VladimirSerykh, it's all part of the learning process

Comment: "The Javascript code is too bulky" — It's shorter than the jQuery code (which is the code you provided, plus the parts of the jQuery library which do the loop that your non-jQuery code does, plus the parts of the jQuery library that you aren't using).

Comment: @Quentin, yes I'm aware of that. When I said bulky, it wasn't in terms of what you said, it was just the lines of code I had to write for JS.

Comment: My point was that people write helper libraries like jQuery for a reason. If you don't want to do things the long way, then the best way to deal with that is usually to use code written by someone else.

Comment: The reason I posted this question was to understand how jQuery selectors worked. For eg. $('p'). I wanted to know if the underlying mechanism looped through every 'p' tag or if there's regex involved. I googled to find out how jQuery selectors actually selected elements but couldn't find much

Comment: @Sidsec9 In that case, look up [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) - iirc that's what jQuery uses under the hood for selectors.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, That's a lot of regex there! Thank you!

Comment: The answer to this is question is simply *"no"*, there's no way to iterate over a nodeList without iterating. Best case, this question belongs on code-review, voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

You can use event delegation - add a click handler to a higher level element and check `event.target`

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "p") alert("click succeeded");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jdkr3sch/

Comment: This doesn't work. Or rather, it only works if there is nothing but text in the paragraph. As soon as you add any element, even an innocent `<span>`, clicking on that child element won't trigger the alert.

Comment: As a side note, `nodeName` is usually a better choice  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename  And ya, you should check for any ascendant node or node itself being a P element

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It's wrong to say "this doesn't work" but that is a noteworthy caveat.  Once you add in the check for descendants you're back to the bulk that OP wanted to avoid though.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery is "less code" because you're calling a pre-written function. Don't want to use jQuery? Then write your own functions.

```
function addEventToElements(tagname,handler) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
    for(var i = 0, l = elems.length; i<l; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener('click',handler);
    }
}
```

Now in your actual code, you can just write:

```
addEventToElements('p',function() {alert("click succeeded");});
```

Congratulations, you have re-invented jQuery.

... Or not, because the reason jQuery is so popular is that it does a *lot* more. Things like normalising browser support (for those that use `attachEvent` or the old `onEventName` handlers) are half the reason jQuery exists, and you'd have to account for all of them in your own re-invention ;)

Comment: If we want to be really pedantic, this still missing some support for browsers which don't support `addEventListener()` method, so no, this isn't equivalent to jQuery method :)

Comment: @A.Wolff What about jQuery 2.0 then? :p

Comment: Ok then... But you could mention it in answer itself maybe

Comment: @A.Wolff There we go, added a note ^^

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter way.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.matches('p, p *')) alert('Paragraph clicked!');
    }, false);
}, false);
```

Notes:

1) This has the advantage of event delegation, which is something I'd suggest looking into. In a nutshell, means you bind the event once, not N times, and then interrogate which element fired it when it fires, i.e. in the callback, not at the point of declaring the event as you are currently.

2) For waiting to use elements, use the `DOMContentLoaded` event rather than `window.onload` - the former is (loosely) analogous to jQuery's DOM ready handler.

3) `matches()` is a relatively modern method and won't work in ancient browsers, or may need a vendor-prefixed version - http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector

Comment: This is functionally identical to Dennis' answer, and suffers the same problem. `<p><span>Can't touch this.</span></p>`

Answer (score 1):

for selecting:

```
document.querySelectorAll('p')
```

(also for more than one element `p` ).

AFAIK this is the closest thing to `$('p')`

---

```
addEventListener('click',function(){alert("click successful!")}
```

to add click handler to single element.

---

to simulate an array you can use the `[].slice.call` on the dom element collection (in this way you use `.forEach()` method) .

---

all together:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('p')).
forEach(function(x){x.addEventListener('click',
    function(){alert("click successful!")
})})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maio/m861hbmh/