# Is there an alternative to element.tagName?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, chromium

I am working with a pretty old version (Chromium 25) of chromium. I would like to use `tagName` to get the name of the used HTML tag. I know that `Element.tagName` works for 43+ chromium versions, but is there an alternative that I can use for older versions?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName        .    
                                    

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need `nodeName`

From `tagName` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

> For Element objects, the value of tagName is the same as the value of the nodeName property the element object inherits from Node.

Below screenshoot is *Browser compatibility* for `tagName`

[image]

```js
const el = document.getElementById('test')
console.log(el.tagName)
console.log(el.nodeName)
```

```html
<span id="test">Example</span>
```

Comment: You could use a pipe e.g. `const tagName = el.tagName | el.nodeName` to always get one or the other. Alternatively, you could create a shim or polyfill for `Element.tagName` to return the `nodeName`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl sure thing, thanks, separated log here is just for demonstration

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I assume you mean the logical OR rather than the bitwise OR? I don't believe the latter will give you anything sensible.

Comment: @Ivar You're right, my mistake... `const tagName = el.tagName || el.nodeName`