# jquery - check the type of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I determine what's the type of a element?

For example, I have a function that's hooked on all elements that have a certain class. These elements can be textareas, iframes, divs etc. I want to find out what kind of element is the current one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/vKz3f/)

HTML:

```
<span class="some"></span>
<div class="some"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.some').each( function ( index ) {
    document.write(index + ':' + $(this).attr("tagName").toLowerCase() + '<br/>');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [Element Selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to get specific type elements.

And use tagName to get the type of a specific element.

[How can I determine the element type of a matched element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341900/how-can-i-determine-the-element-type-of-a-matched-element-in-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

You can call attr("tagName"):

```
$("a").attr("tagName");
```