# JQuery: Convert to & from textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery & I am attempting to do some things which I am not sure I can do in JQuery.

- Can I get a HTML elements type using a JQuery(or maybe even a native Javascript) function? If so, what is the name of the function?
- I want to update/set a HTML elements class attribute. Would you suggest I use just plain old setAttribute() for this or should I use a JQuery function? If I should use a JQuery function whats the name of the function?
- Is there a javascript function that returns a HTML elements class? Is it this.getAttribute("class");?

More experienced JQuery Programmers: How would you improve this JQuery HTML code that attempts to change elements to textarea's then back again(some functionality is missing right now):

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var STATE = 0;

        function Toggle()
        {
            if (STATE==1) { convertToUpdatable(); STATE = 0; }
            else          { convertToStatic();    STATE = 1; }
        }

        function convertToUpdatable()
        {
            // Post: Convert all HTML elements (with the class 'updatable') to textarea HTML elements
            //       and store their HTML element type in the class attribute
            // EG: Before: <p class="updatable"/> Hello this is some text 1 </p>
            //     After : <textarea class="updatable p"/> Hello this is some text 1 </textarea>

            $(".updatable").each(function()
                {
                    $(this).replaceWith("<textarea>"+$(this).text() +"</textarea>");
                    // TODO store this elements type in class attribute
                    // The below is guessing that there are jquery functions getType()
                    $(this).setAttribute( "class", $(this).getAttribute("class") + $(this).getType() );
                });
        }

        function convertToStatic()
        {
            // Post: Find all HTML elements (with the class 'updatable'), check to see if they are part of another class aswell
            //       (which will be their original HTML element type) & convert the element back to that original HTML element type

            $(".updatable").each(function()
                {
                    // This uses javascript functions: how can I write this in JQuery
                    var type = this.getAttribute("class").replace("updatable","").replace(" ", "");

                    if (type == "") { alert("Updatable element had no type defined in class attribute"); return; }

                    $(this).replaceWith( type +$(this).text() + type );
                    $(this).setAttribute( "class", "updatable" );
                });
        }

    -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p class="updatable"/> Hello this is some text 1 </p>
    <b class="updatable"/> Hello this is some text 2 </b>
    <i class="updatable"/> Hello this is some text 3 </i>

    <input id="MyButton" type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="Toggle();" />

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are links for your first three questions:

1. [How can I determine the element type of a matched element in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/341900/440704)
2. http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
3. http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
your_element.className = 'some_class';
your_element.nodeName;
```