# Get element type with jQuery

Tags: jquery, element

Is it possible, using jQuery, to find out the type of an element with jQuery? For example, is the element a div, span, select, or input?

For example, if I am trying to load values into a drop-down list with jQuery, but the same script can generate code into a set of radio buttons, could I create something like:

```
$('.trigger').live('click', function () {
   var elementType = $(this).prev().attr(WHAT IS IT);
});
```

Given a drop-down list with a button next to it with the **trigger** class, my `elementType` variable should return `select` upon the button being pressed.

Comment: Can you rephrase? what do you mean by element type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine the element type of a matched element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341900/how-can-i-determine-the-element-type-of-a-matched-element-in-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding the type of an element using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608410/finding-the-type-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 635, accepted):

Getting the element type the jQuery way:

```
var elementType = $(this).prev().prop('nodeName');
```

doing the same without jQuery

```
var elementType = this.previousSibling.nodeName;
```

Checking for specific element type:

```
var is_element_input = $(this).prev().is("input"); //true or false
```

Comment: Just remember that the .prop() function was only added in jQuery 1.6 - you may need to upgrade the version you're using!

Comment: Didn't work with old jQuery 1.3.2, so upgraded to latest and it worked fine.

Comment: It's probably my version of jQuery, but only the last one worked for me.  $(this).is("input") .  Thanks for including multiple ways.

Comment: how about 'jqueryElementObject'.tagName

Comment: This could be improved by switching 'tagName' to 'nodeName' as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename).

Comment: @KyleStoflet - it seems you're right, `nodeName` does support more types of elements, and supporting IE5.5 shouldn't be an issue any more, so I see no issues with changing `tagName` to `nodeName` in the above answer. Both will work just fine for elements, and the latter will work on textnodes, attributes etc. as well.

Comment: Works but I got a bit confused by the prev(), which is specific for the example code in question. Basically, `$(this).is("input");`

Comment: @Fanky - That's correct, the OP is specifically asking for the *previous* element, hence then `prev()` call. The rest of the answer is applicable to any other circumstance where one might need to know the type of tag or check the tagname etc.

Answer (score 67):

also you can use:

```
$("#elementId").get(0).tagName
```

Answer (score 25):

you should use `tagName` property and `attr('type')` for inputs

Comment: An example would make this comment stronger.

Answer (score 20):

As Distdev alluded to, you still need to differentiate the input type. That is to say,

```
$(this).prev().prop('tagName');
```

will tell you `input`, but that doesn't differentiate between checkbox/text/radio. If it's an input, you can then use

```
$('#elementId').attr('type');
```

to tell you checkbox/text/radio, so you know what kind of control it is.

Answer (score 13):

you can use `.is()`:

```
  $( "ul" ).click(function( event ) {
      var target = $( event.target );
      if ( target.is( "li" ) ) {
         target.css( "background-color", "red" );
      }
  });
```

see [source](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 4):

use get(0).tagName. [See this link](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-how-to-get-the-tag-name/)

Answer (score 3):

Use Nodename over tagName :

> nodeName contains all functionalities of tagName, plus a few more. Therefore nodeName is always the better choice.

see [DOM Core](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/)