# Get the type of the HTML element from a jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get element type with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388470/get-element-type-with-jquery)

Preamble: I'm Italian, sorry for my bad English.

From an html code like this:

```
<input class="myElem" />
<input class="myElem" />
<div class="myElem"></div>
<ul class="myElem"></ul>
<input class="myElem" />
```

is there a way to retrieve the html objects type?

something like:

```
$('.myElem').each(function () {
      var htmlType = $(this).type() //Example
      console.log(htmlType);
});

/* Log:
*    input
*    input
*    div
*    ul
*    input
*/
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$('.myElem').each(function () {
      var htmlType = $(this).prop('tagName') //Example
      console.log(htmlType);
});
```