# how to link twitter bootstrap tabs from hyper link on otherpages

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am using bootstrap tab on a page and now i want to make links from other page. 
like
Tab1
Tab2

please Guide me how to make a hyper link on a tab use in other page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428779/show-tab-with-external-link-with-onclick-in-bootstrap-3-2-0/26430204#26430204

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap tabs are just like any other hyperlinks. You need to set the href to the page that you want to link to with the tab. If you want the other page to have the tab highlighted, use `class="active"` on the tab that you want to be shown to be active.

Comment: I think the OP wants to link to a tab from another page and that requires jQuery, it's not built in. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428779/show-tab-with-external-link-with-onclick-in-bootstrap-3-2-0/26430204#26430204