# Externally Linking to a Tab, Tab not changing, Bootstrap 3.3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

My issue is very similar to these questions, where I am trying to use a link to change tabs, but the link only changes the tab content, but not the active tab.

Most Similar: [Bootstrap linking to a tab with an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625211/bootstrap-linking-to-a-tab-with-an-url)

Pretty Similar: [show tab with external link with onclick in bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428779/show-tab-with-external-link-with-onclick-in-bootstrap-3?lq=1)

However I am currently not finding success with either of these solutions, perhaps because I have a different version of bootstrap (or maybe because I'm just doing something dumb :p we'll see)

Here's my code

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang=''>
    <head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>

    <!-- For Dynamic Tabs-->    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <!--Begin Page Code-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="font-size: 20px">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active" >
    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Link to 2</a><br>
    <a href="#tab3"  data-toggle="tab">Link to 3</a><br>
    <a href="#tab3"  data-toggle="tab">Another Link to 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p> This is tab 2 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p> This is tab 3 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
    <p> This is tab 4 </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--End Page Code-->

    </body>
    <html>
```

Where script2.js is where I am trying to implement solutions. Currently this one from [Bootstrap linking to a tab with an url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625211/bootstrap-linking-to-a-tab-with-an-url)

```
    $(function () {
        $('#tab1 a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').tab('show');
        })
    });
```

Anyone know how to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are including your script file before you import jQuery and the bootstrap javascript files.

Since your code requires both of these libraries, you need to move your `script2.js` underneath your other scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

Your browsers javascript console will contain a message along the lines of:

> $ is not defined.

this should always be the first place you look.

Your code works fine when used correctly: http://www.bootply.com/zP1y6wJIl1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.location.href` to get something like `http://domain.com/index.html#tab1`

(not tested) but you could put:

```
if (window.location.href.replace("#", "") == "tab1")
{
  //change tab
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You many want to change your links to:

```
<a href="javascript:$('a[href=#tab2]').click()" >Link to 2</a><br>
<a href="javascript:$('a[href=#tab3]').click()">Link to 3</a><br>
<a href="javascript:$('a[href=#tab4]').click()">Another Link to 3</a>
```