# Bootstrap 4 - Use an footer link to show a tab content

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

Im using the navigation tools from Bootstrap 4, having a tab navigation with 4 tabs, each showing its content. All this works fine.

Now I decided to place the last tab, the imprint, in a footer. But the functionality shall remain the same as before: I want to click on the link in the footer and display the tab content. Furthermore, the active link from the current page shall be gone (like when normally changing a tab).

I made a simple demonstration in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7gwkcsr4/30/

My imprint link is in the footer at the bottom of the page.
What do I have to do, that the link behaves just like it was still a part of the tab content?

I hoped that the `data-toggle="tab"` on the a href would still do the trick even if not being in the navbar wrapper, but when clicking on it, console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined`. Without the data-toggle, just nothing happens.

What can be done to make this work? Do I have to use JS/jQ like shown [in this SO question using BS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867556/externally-linking-to-a-tab-tab-not-changing-bootstrap-3-3-5), or can it be done using only html?

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Bootstrap 4 JS tries to find the `.active` tab in the parent (should be the nav `<div>`) of the tabs, which it can't find as the link is in a other place in the code. This means that there isn't a non-JS solution to your problem.

However, I've created a pretty clean (JS) solution that should work for you:

- We have the imprint tab in the list of other tabs, but it has a id `imprint-tab` and a extra class `d-none` (makes it hidden)
- The link you want to toggle the tab with has the id `toggle-imprint` which our short jQuery snippet will find
- jQuery will run the `$('#imprint-tab').tab('show')` function (`.tab('show')` docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabshow))

Basically when we click on the link in the footer, the `#imprint-tab` will be toggled (deselecting the last tab) and the tab content will be shown.

```js
$("#toggle-imprint").click(function(){
  $('#imprint-tab').tab('show');
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative; 
  min-height: 100%
}
footer {
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav-link {
    color: black;
}
.nav-link.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js,npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav">
    <a href="#nav-home" class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    <a href="#nav-content1" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Content1</a>
    <a href="#nav-content2" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Content2</a>
    <!-- Not anymore, moved to footer now! -->
    <a id="imprint-tab" href="#nav-imprint" class="nav-item nav-link d-none" data-toggle="tab">Imprint</a>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
  <div id="nav-home" class="tab-pane fade show active">
    Hello HOME
  </div>
  <div id="nav-content1" class="tab-pane fade">
    Hello Content 1
  </div>
  <div id="nav-content2" class="tab-pane fade">
    Hello Content 2
  </div>
  <div id="nav-imprint" class="tab-pane fade">
    Hello Imprint
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <a id="toggle-imprint" href="#">Imprint</a>
</footer>
```

*I'm also using Bootstrap 4 stable in the example, but this works aswell in the version you are using. Make sure to upgrade when possible!*