# How to check element type in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have  a situation in which i want to  convert a `<select>` tag into a `<input type="text">` and `<input type="text">` into `<select>` bu using some condition.
So how can i know that **this element a type text or type select using id attribute.**

Comment: `select` is not an input, so there is no `select` type. Input's `type` property and HTMLElement's `nodeType` property are 2 different things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get element type with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388470/get-element-type-with-jquery)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `tagName` instead of `nodeType`.

Comment: And whats your condition ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using

```
$("#inputID").attr("type");
```

If you alert above you will get the type of input element, then you can apply checks accordingly.

Ref here : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

UPDATE

check using

```
if(!$("#inputID").is("select")) {
    // the input field is not a select
}
```

got from a link while searching not tested though.

Comment: It shows undefied for select tag but it works fine for <input> tag

Answer (score 12):

And also a pure javascript solution:

```
function toggle(a){
    if(a.tagName === 'INPUT'){
        a.outerHTML = '<select id="toggle"></select>';
    }else{
        a.outerHTML = '<input type="text" id="toggle"/>'
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M6qXZ/1/

### 2018 ES6

```
e => e.outerHTML = e.tagName === "INPUT" ? "<select id='toggle'></select>" : "<input id='toggle'/>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to test whether the elements is of type x like

Use [:text](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) selector to test for text input element

```
if($("#inputID").is(":text")){
    //to test for text type
}
```

Use [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to test for select element

```
if($("#inputID").is("select")){
    //to test for select
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the element type using jQuery:

`var elementType = $("#myid").prop('tagName');`

Get the input type attribute using jQuery:

`var inputType = $("#myid").attr('type');`

Answer (score 1):

the condicion could be for example:

```
   if($('#whateverid').attr('type') == "text")
```