# Is it possible to know the content type of the cell in a HTML table using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to store the contents of a HTML table in an array in Javascript.
To do so, I would like to know the content type (text/dropdown/input box) of each cell before accessing the content of the cell, so that I can access the cell value accordingly.
Kindly guide me how to get to know the content type beforehand.

Comment: did you look at the cells javascript object?
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp

Comment: What about the first answer here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388470/get-element-type-with-jquery

Comment: @Enjoyted [Please don't use w3schools as a resource!!](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @nietonfir interesting, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by “content type of a cell”? HTML has no such concept. You can inspect, with the usual DOM tools, what the content is, but it has no “type”. If you know that the content is always a control (form field) element only, you can inspect its `type` property.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="something"></td>
        <td><select id="something_else"></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>

document.getElementById("something").tagName;
//returns: input

document.getElementById("something_else").tagName;
//returns: select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function getValue(cell) { //cell is a ref to table.cell
   var child = cell.firstChild;
   if(cell.childNodes.length > 1) {//how do you define value for multiple?
      console.log('Multiple children not supported');
      return;
   }

   if(child.nodeType === 3) { //text node
      return child.textContent;
   }
   if(child.nodeType === 1) { //elements
      switch (child.tagName) { //implement behaviour based on node's tagName
          case 'INPUT': return child.value;
          case 'SELECT': return child.options[child.selectedIndex].value;
          default: return child.innerHTML; //?
      }
   }
}
```