# jQuery - get element type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to get an element type in jQuery.

If I click on something I would like the console.log to write out what kind of element I clicked, if it is a link, button, checkbox and so on.

Something like this:

```
console.log("time: " + Date() + "  element type: " + $.(this).type);
```

This does not work, except for the date which works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get element type with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388470/get-element-type-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `nodeName` property of the DOM object. There is no need to create a new jQuery object for this:

```
console.log("time: " + Date() + " element type: " + this.nodeName);
```

`this` is the element containing the click event. If you want to know which element inside it got clicked you can use the target property of the event object:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    console.log("time: " + Date() + " element type: " + event.target.nodeName);
});
```

For the difference between `nodeName` and `tagName` see also [this question on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878484/difference-between-tagname-and-nodename)