# Detecting the element clicked on jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have a form in Which contains a number`input`s and `textarea`s.  How do I identify which one is currently clicked on?

```
   $('body').on('change', 'input textarea', function() {

            })
```

In other words,How detect which type is currently clicked, `input`s or `textarea`s?

Comment: Use `this`, eg `var element = $(this)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How detect which type is currently clicked, inputs or textareas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/is or `this.tagName`

Comment: Also note that the selector needs to have a comma separator so it becomes 'or' logic: `'input, textarea'`

Comment: To get the element type that was changed please read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388470/get-element-type-with-jquery

Comment: Simple solution is to create a separate eventhandler for each type and handle it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can try like this forms also have an elements collection, sometimes this differs from children such as when the form tag is in a table and is not closed.

```
$("form").each(function(){
  $(this).find(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to what the OP has asked, and what they are attempting to achieve. You seem to have misunderstood the question.